# Hide sub-category from top-menu

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

How can i remove/hide  the sub-category from the opencart  menu under dropdown Components .
Website url : http://cart.kashmosoft.com/

Comment: like i want to to hide montors from components

Answer (score 1):

There is an option through which you can hide parent categories from top menu. Go to categories > Edit category > Data tab and you will see below image.

[image: top]

But above option will work for only parent categories and to make it work for child categories like monitors follow below steps:

Go to file /catalog/controller/common/header.php
Search term 'top' and you will notice 1 occurrence and below code is written.

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
        //...... some code written
        }
}
```

You have edit this block of code as below

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
        //...... some code written
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                if ($child['top']) {  // **YOU HAVE TO ADD IF CONDITION**
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
                }
            }
        //...some extra code written
        }
}
```

And done mark top for each category but not for monitors.